Spectrum of Bose liquid in AGD
This question comes from the revised English translation of "Methods of Quantum Field Theory in Statistical Physics" (AGD). In Eq. (1.8), the authors have written the total energy of a Bose liquid in Fourier components:
$$
E=\underbrace{E^{(1)}(\tilde{\rho})}_{\small\mbox{unperturbed energy}}+\frac{1}{V}\sum_{\bf{p}}\left(\frac{|\dot{\rho_{\bf{p}}}|^2}{2\tilde{\rho}p^2}+\frac12\,\varphi_{\bf{p}}|{\rho_{\bf{p}}}|^2\right)
$$
where $\tilde{\rho}$ is the equilibrium density, $V$ is the volume occupied by the liquid, $\rho_{\bf{p}}$ are the Fourier components of perturbations to $\tilde{\rho}$ due to long-wavelength phonons, and $\varphi_{\bf{p}}$ are the Fourier components of a translationally-symmetric function $\varphi$. The authors use the virial theorem to relate $\varphi_{\bf{p}}$ to the ground state energy of each oscillator:
$$
\langle E\rangle
=\frac{\hbar\omega_{\bf{p}}}{2}
=2\langle U\rangle
=\langle \varphi_{\bf{p}}|{\rho_{\bf{p}}}|^2\rangle
\overset{?}{=}\varphi_{\bf{p}}\langle |{\rho_{\bf{p}}}|^2\rangle
$$
The last line is the part I'm unsure about - how can $\varphi_{\bf{p}}$ be taken out of the expectation value?
